# Dead D7000 rear LCD?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000, lcd

So, Ive been shooting a Nikon D7000 for 2 years to the day (i received mine from B&H on october 28th 2011). last friday, i was taking a few shots of my friends son, and wanted to record a short clip of what he was doing as well. as soon as i flicked the switch for liveview mode, i noticed that the screen was terribly dark, as if i had the exposure set waaaaay off. the thing is, it wasnt. i was at ISO 100 with the shutter speed at 1oo and F2.8. i dialed it down to 50, no change. i set the iso higher, also no change. i turned it off and on a few times, nada. then, i took the battery out, and put it back and i saw the top display read ERR, without any further code or message. it wouldnt shoot, or do anything other than make that message for a minute or two while i removed and reinserted the battery a few times. then, after i turned it back on after what must have been 4-6 off and on's, it just started normally, and would shoot and operate fine, only it wouldnt display anything on the rear screen. i checked the card after putting it in my computer and sure enough, its still shooting correctly and focusing well and everthing else, i just cant get the screen to show at all. it hadnt been dropped or exposed  to any weird conditions at all at the time of the screen failing, it just made the error message on the top screen and that was that. my question is, has anyone else had this happen? ive seen other people have the screen go all screwy and have lines and other things show up but its usually with other problems as well. i havent seen anyone on any of the forums have JUST the problem i have though. its not under warranty and though i use my camera heavily (i shoot daily), it is in pretty good condition otherwise. ive had no other problems with this camera at all, just this. any help, similar stories or fixes would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is kind of an imposing wall of text. Can you clarify what the question is exactly? Have you contacted Nikon service?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would recommend:

1. Try a second lens that is in known working condition
2. Reset user settings by entering your Menu> Settings menu(pg 76 in your manual)
3. Restore default settings by holding the QUAL and +/- buttons together for > 2 seconds(pg 151 in your manual)
4. Reset all custom settings(pg 296 in your manual)
5. Consult a Nikon-authorized service center

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback! i did the reset using the QUAL and +/- keys but the other ones i cant do given that its my screen that doesnt work so i cant navigate the menu. im giving Nikon a call now.